# Symfony rewrite route WelcomeController

Tags: php, symfony1, routes, controller

I created a new bundle on a Symfony project, and I want to use the / route on a page such as:

```
JhebergUserBundle_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: JhebergUserBundle:Default:index }
```

On the production environment it works perfectly, but in development environment, it doesn't. I always have the "*Congratulations! You have successfully installed a new Symfony application.*" page.
How can I rewrite the route on development environment ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is admittedly a tad confusing for newcomers to Symfony, because the homepage route isn't found in `app/config/routing.yml`. The route you are looking for is actually defined in `app/config/routing_dev.yml`:

```
_welcome:
  pattern:  /                
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }
```

Remove this route, and then define the homepage route anew in your respective bundle, and everything will work as expected.